# Issue with callback garbage collected

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer, pinvoke

I am receiving an error "A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type" using this code, but I cant seem to find the solution.

```
<DllImport("winmm.dll")>
Private Shared Function timeSetEvent(delay As Integer, resolution As Integer, handler As TimerEventHandler, user As IntPtr, eventType As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("winmm.dll")>
Private Shared Function timeBeginPeriod(millisecond As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub OnLoadit()
    timeBeginPeriod(1)
    Dim mHandler As New TimerEventHandler(AddressOf TimerCallback)
    Dim mTimerId As Integer = timeSetEvent(4, 0, mHandler, IntPtr.Zero, 1)
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub TimerEventHandler(id As Integer, msg As Integer, user As IntPtr, dw1 As Integer, dw2 As Integer)
Private Sub TimerCallback(id As Integer, msg As Integer, user As IntPtr, dw1 As Integer, dw2 As Integer)
    'my function code here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaning `mHandler` into a class member (e.g. a private field) as currently it is scoped to the `OnLoadit` method so that after its execution `mHandler` can be collected via GC at the moment.

Comment: thanks, if this safe to run as an alternative to the Timer for performing a function every 3 milliseconds?

Comment: Well I would deal as long with managed code as possible but if the resolution of .NET's Timer does not fit your needs and this does then sure go ahead with it. One thing to note however is that you should deal with cleaning up, i.e. implement IDisposable so that when your whole object goes out of scope it gets rid of the created timer as otherwise the same error will occur